# How much caffeine is in matcha powder?

Tags: tea, nutrient-composition, caffeine

I would like to know how many milligrams of caffeine are there in a gram of dried matcha powder.

Comment: An interesting sub-question: When using for green tea, how much matcha powder *typically* remains in the cup after the tea is consumed.

Comment: @Kingsley I thought you were supposed to drink the entire powder at the bottom of the cup too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(google is your friend)

About [35 mg of caffeine in 1 gram](https://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-content/matcha-green-tea) of matcha.

Comment: Nice find. I turned away from that website as soon as I saw that the unit of measurement for matcha is "cups", which can be anything. However, as you found, the text reveals that they use 2 grams per cup. My face is lost and deservedly so.